# If $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ then $P(A\cap B^c)=P(A)P(B^c)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

If $A$ and $B$ are independent such that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$, how can I show $P(A\cap B^c)=P(A)P(B^c)$?

I have been thinking of showing this using something like:

$P(A\cap B^c)=1-P(A^c\cup B)=1-P(A^c)-P(B)+P(A^c\cap B)$

but I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\mathbb P(A)=\mathbb P((A\cap B^c)\cup (A\cap B))=\mathbb P(A\cap B^c)+\mathbb P(A\cap B)$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Note that $P(A)=P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^C)$.  Can you use what you already know about $P(A\cap B)$ to rearrange this usefully?